# Transform an element property into an attribute of the particular element

Tags: enterprise-architect, jscript

Since I'm a fairly new user when it comes to the Enterprise Architect, I'm stuck at this problem.

I need to write a script to transform each item marked as `<<property>>` in the class diagram, into an attribute of that particular class.

So far, I've come to this and I am not sure how can I change each property into an attribute.

When I try to add a new attribute like this:

```
selectedObject.Attributes.AddNew("example", "int");
```

It crashes with an error that this collection is null or not an object.

Even when I add an attribute to the class manually and then try to access it with the method `selectedObject.Attributes.GetAt(0);` it still crashes with the error:
`Script.script 'Attributes' is null or not an object, Line: 39.`

Below is my full code:

```
var currentDiagram as EA.Diagram;
currentDiagram = Repository.GetCurrentDiagram();

if ( currentDiagram != null )
{
    // Get a reference to any selected connector/objects
    var selectedObjects as EA.Collection;
    selectedObjects = currentDiagram.SelectedObjects();

    if ( selectedObjects.Count > 0 )
    {
        // One or more diagram objects are selected
        var selectedObject as EA.Element;

        for(var i = 0; i < selectedObjects.Count; ++i)
        {
            selectedObject = selectedObjects.GetAt(i);

            Session.Output(selectedObject.Attributes.GetAt(0));

            selectedObject.Attributes.AddNew("example", "int");
        }

        Session.Output(selectedObject.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Please indicate the language you are using (with the appropriate tag), the **exact** error message you are getting and a minimal complete example of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectedObjects = currentDiagram.SelectedObjects();
```

returns diagram elements. You need to retrieve the element first.

```
elemId = selectedObjects.getat(0).elementId:
element = Repository.GetElementByID(elemId);
```

will return the first element of selected diagram elements.

---

**Previous bug**

Actually your code uses

```
selectedObject.Attributes.AddNew();
```

which of course won't work since you need (as you mentioned above) to supply two parameters: the name and the (eventually blank) type. Note that the name must be unique.

So it should be

```
attr = selectedObject.Attributes.AddNew("theName", "someType");
attr.update();
```

(Sorry, I don't know how to declare a new variable `attr` in the language you use.)

Comment: Even when I add the name and the type for the new attribute, it still crashes with the same error that Attributes is null or not an object.

Comment: Okay that did the trick. But I could not access the element Id directly with `selectedObject = selectedObjects.GetAt(i).elementId;`

I had to create an additional variable. Firstly, you have to store each object from the `selectedObjects` list to that variable `selectedObject` for example and from here you can extract the ID.

I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Different languages behave different. Though I can read that Java dialect you use, i can't write any code out of the blue which would be syntactically correct :-)